# How to write inline assembly in gnu pascal?

Tags: pascal, inline-assembly

Since there is not offical reference,I got only one tutorial 
 [gpcasm.zip](http://www.gnupascal.de/contrib/misc/gpcasm.zip) .But when I try to follow the tut and try the inline assembly example on my debian.The gpc was not happy with it.

```
gnu_asm.pas : In procedure 'MyStupidDelay':
gnu_asm.pas:3: error : can't find a register in class AREG while reloading asm
```

Here is the code

```
program gnu_asm;
Procedure MyStupidDelay(time : integer);
Begin
 Asm("0 : pushl $0xfffff
   1 : decl(%%esp)
     jnz 1b
    addl $0x4, %%esp
    decl %%eax
    jnz 0b"
    :
    : "a" (time)
    : "eax" );
end;

begin
 write("only for test");
end.
```

Another question,are there any other refernece, tutorials, examples on inline assembly in gnu pascal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may not be the pascal part but the assembler part.

See [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-04/msg00205.html) for a similar problem.

For more info pls state your target machine and infos on the compile options.